# What is the solution to this blank in the code?

Tags: ruby, koan

This is from the [test_symbols_cannot_be_concatenated](https://github.com/edgecase/ruby_koans/blob/master/koans/about_symbols.rb#L86) exercise in the [Ruby Koans](http://rubykoans.com/). Previous exercises had used `assert_equal` tests. This is the first `assert_raise` on the path to enlightenment.

```
def test_symbols_cannot_be_concatenated

  assert_raise(_____) do
    :cats + :dogs
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`NoMethodError` I guess, since it makes no sense to try to sum or catenate two symbols.

Comment: Please don't post answers to homework questions. Instead, post hints to help the OP figure it out on his own.

Comment: @Joerg: I suspect it's a ruby koan. If this is homework, it indicates the teacher themself is plagiarizing!

Answer (score 0):

The error message I received was (line-breaks added for readability):

```
[] exception expected, not  Class: <NoMethodError>   
Message: <"undefined method `+' for :cats:Symbol">    
---Backtrace---    
/Ruby_on_Rails/koans/about_symbols.rb:89:in   
`block in test_symbols_cannot_be_concatenated'
```

Following the pattern I thought I had established of looking for "expected but was", I thought the answer would be "`exception`".  That clearly didn't work, but based on noodl's answer, I realized that for an `assert_raise()` the clue is the Class that is expected to be called, in this case <`NoMethodError`>.

This seems to be consistent with documentation at [APIdock](http://apidock.com/ruby/Test/Unit/Assertions/assert_raise) which indicates the args are each being evaluated as a `__check_exception_class`